# Detecting the Secondary mouse button in the text area and table view using javafx

Tags: javafx-2

private void gotoRightClick() {

```
     textArea.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            if(event.isSecondaryButtonDown())
            {
                System.out.println("right click pressed in text area");
            }
        }
    });

  tableView.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
            if(e.isSecondaryButtonDown())
            {
                System.out.println("right click pressed in table view");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

None of the event is detecting can any one help me?
Thanks Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
this.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                if (event.getButton().equals(MouseButton.SECONDARY)) {
                    //do something
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Hi amru in the above code i want to perform the right click operation on the both the text area and table view for text area it is working for table view it is not working

Comment: Try this:

    table_view.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                if (event.getButton().equals(MouseButton.SECONDARY)) {
                    System.out.println("right click on table. it is executed in my case");
                }

                if (event.isSecondaryButtonDown()) {
                    System.out.println("this is never executed");
                }
            }
        });